# Interface redeclaration in Go in aws-sdk-v2: is it correct?

Tags: go, interface

In aws-sdk-v2 library for Go, we have the following interfaces definitions:

```
type Retryer interface {
    GetInitialToken() (releaseToken func(error) error)
}


type RetryerV2 interface {
    Retryer
    
    GetInitialToken() (releaseToken func(error) error)
}
```

(the code is here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/aws/retryer.go)

This causes compilation error:

```
aws/retryer.go:81: GetInitialToken redeclared (compile)
```

Is this code correct or not? Is it possible to redeclare function in of interfaces?
How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you are using an old version of Go. Overlapping method sets are allowed since Go 1.14, and the code compiles on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/o66CV9b9hAv).

Quoting from [Go 1.14 release log:](https://go.dev/doc/go1.14)

> Per the [overlapping interfaces proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/6977-overlapping-interfaces.md), Go 1.14 now permits embedding of interfaces with overlapping method sets: methods from an embedded interface may have the same names and identical signatures as methods already present in the (embedding) interface. This solves problems that typically (but not exclusively) occur with diamond-shaped embedding graphs. Explicitly declared methods in an interface must remain [unique](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Uniqueness_of_identifiers), as before.

If you get a compile-time error for the code you posted, that suggests you're using a Go prior to 1.14. Urgently update! Please note that only the last 2 major versions are supported (currently 1.17 and 1.16). You using a version like 1.13 is a major risk!

Comment: I use `go1.16.14`, but maybe there are some static checkers in the path, that could cause this?

Comment: @IgorChubin The code you posted works on the Go Playground (see link in my question). If you're using Go 1.16, likely this isn't the part that fails to compile.

Comment: Although the error does point to this line, I still think you're using another version of Go than what you think you are.

Comment: If you're sure you use Go 1.16, try to compile from the command line with `go` (and not from an IDE) to see if the error goes away.

Comment: As I said before, I am using go1.16.14, but it is possible that I have some linters/static-checkers in my PATH. You answered my questions. Thanks a lot